# Ordinary differential equation -plotting $\operatorname{Si}(x)$ graph in mathematica

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I graph using CAS $y =10x^{-2}(\operatorname{Si}(x) - \operatorname{Si}(1)) $ where

$$\operatorname{Si}(x) =\int_0^x\frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx $$

For $x>0$.

Comment: Here's the command for the sine integral: "SinIntegral[x]".

Comment: Can it be used in mathematica

Comment: Yes. That is the Mathematica command.

Comment: Still have difficulty in plotting

Comment: i tried Plot[BesselJ[0, (10*x^-2)(
    SinIntegral[x]) - (10*x^-2)(SinIntegral[1])], {x, -0, 5}]

Comment: Why do you have Bessel if that is not in your problem? Is what I posted what you were looking for? Just change the range of $x$ as desired. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets plot it so we see the singularity at the origin.

**Plot[(10*(-SinIntegral[1] + SinIntegral[x]))/x^2, {x, -50, 50}]**

[image]

Now lets plot it for $x>0$.

**Plot[(10*(-SinIntegral[1] + SinIntegral[x]))/x^2, {x, 0, 50}]**

[image]

Comment: x>0, so -50 becomes invalid

Comment: I added both plots, the first is showing the singularity at the origin, while the second is showing $x>0$, however, that is very clear from the first. Regards

Comment: I MISSED THE MOMENT WHEN YOU EXCEEDED $$\Large \mathbb {20} \mathbb K!!!$$ Congratulations! While you've long been a *trusted user*, now you've got the official designation!

Comment: I told you that you'd reach 20 K by "week's end" (i.e., by the end of this math.SE week which is 5:00 pm your time today!) ;-)